# How to turn data into a picture (MATLAB)

Tags: image, matlab, vectorization

I am only a novice programmer, and I would like some help with this problem.

I am currently running simulations of particles that interact and move around on a two-dimensional lattice.  The data of where the particles are at any point is stored in a two-dimensional array that I use during the simulation itself.After the simulation, I want to be able to visually see where all of the particles end up. Currently, I send the data to MATLAB, and have it literally plot each particle on a figure.  This works, and creates "pictures" of my system configuration.  However, for large numbers of particles in a large lattice (With dimensions like 600 particles wide by 1200 particles tall), this makes prohibitively slow-processing pictures, that MATLAB and word processing are very slow to deal with, and which uses up a lot of memory and space.

There must be a better way to do this, does anyone have any ideas on better ways to view my system or control the data?

My matlab code works as the following:

```
%--------------------------------------- Particle Picture
clc; clear all;
particle_file = fopen('ABC_Particles_600X1200T1.txt');
particles = fscanf(particle_file,'%f');
fclose(particle_file);

figure(3);
hold on;
sizex = 600;
sizey = 1200;

for a = 1:1:sizey*sizex
    b = int32(a);
    if particles(a) == 0
        plot(mod(b,sizex)+1,idivide(b,sizex)+1,'c')
    end
    if particles(a) == 1
        plot(mod(b,sizex)+1,idivide(b,sizex)+1,'r')
    end
    if particles(a) == 2
        plot(mod(b,sizex)+1,idivide(b,sizex)+1,'k')
    end
end    
title('Size 600X1200; Time T = 1')
axis([0 sizex 0 sizey])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can vectorize your code using logical conditions instead of the loop. for example, `z=(particles==0)` is a vector of `0` and `1`'s, where you get the value `1` where the element of particles=0. This replaces the code:

```
for a=1:n
     if particles(a) == 0
        z(a)=1
    else
        z(a)=0
    end
end
```

So, first we reshape `particles` from a long vector to a matrix:

```
p=reshape(particles,600,1200);
```

then we can use logical conditions as before, or similarly, the function `find` to get the x and y coordinates of the `p` according to what you wrote

```
[x0 y0]=find(p==0);
[x1 y1]=find(p==1);
[x2 y2]=find(p==2);
```

Then we can just plot it:

```
plot(x0,y0,'c',x1,y1,'r',x2,y2,'k')
```

by the way, if `0,1,2` are the only values your data have you can skip all this and just use:

```
imagesc(p)
```

That will color code your points differently, but you can change the [colormap](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) to whatever you want

Comment: THANKS!!! That helped so much.  You just saved me so much time and effort.  Can you explain to me why plotting the points in this way works so much better?

Comment: This happens because you just use plot once and not 600*1200 times. the function `plot` takes time and memory, actually, using plot with a single input `plot(1)` takes 0.0035 seconds (in my machine) So it means that for up to the 600X1200 elements should take ~2500 seconds.

Comment: I've just added an even simpler and faster option at the bottom of my answer. I forgot to tell you, welcome to stack overflow...

Comment: Thanks!  I understand why this is so much faster in plotting itself, but why does it work so much better after the plotting?  Before, once it had plotted my computer was really sluggish if I wanted to do anything like adjust the window dimensions, open up the edit menu, plot tools, ect.  Now it is much faster with that.  But either way, after graphing the graph contains 600X1200 points, so why is one faster than the other here?

Comment: as I said, plot takes also memory. The previous code had a heavy memory load and now that is gone... its not the points of the graph that take memory but the whole procedure to produce it again and again, calling java libraries, setting the gui with all the options, etc.